# Casting to base interface when using covariance and multiple generic parameters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make all these mapper classes have a common base:

```
// base
class BaseInput { public string BaseInputValue { get; set; } }
class BaseOutput { public string BaseOutputValue { get; set; } }

interface IMapper<InputType, out OutputType>
    where InputType : BaseInput
    where OutputType : BaseOutput
{
    OutputType Map(InputType input);
}

// example implementation
class Input : BaseInput { public string InputValue { get; set; } }
class Output : BaseOutput { public string OutputValue { get; set; } }

class MyMapper : IMapper<Input, Output>
{
    public Output Map(Input input)
    {
        // custom mapping done here to Output
        return new Output { /* mapping */ };
    }
}
```

This code to create a new one of these mappers and assign it to the base compiles fine:

```
var myBaseMapper = (IMapper<BaseInput, BaseOutput>) new MyMapper();
```

But I get a runtime error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MyMapper' to type 'IMapper`2[UserQuery+BaseInput,UserQuery+BaseOutput]'.

If I reduce `IMapper` to `IMapper<out OutputType>` it works fine, but then that requires doing a cast in `MyMapper.Map`, which is slightly annoying to have to do in each mapper class. Additionally, that makes me lose the information for deciding which Mapper to use for what `BaseInput` and so I have to define that elsewhere.

Is doing this just not possible in C# or is there a way of doing something similar? If not, I will have to rethink my design.

Comment: Declare `InputType` as covariant: `interface IMapper<in InputType, out OutputType>`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek `InputType` would be *contravariant* in that case

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I tried doing `<in InputType, out OutputType>` before just to see, but I get the same error. By the way, I meant to originally write `covariance` for `out` in the title. I mixed them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this because it doesn't make sense, your interface is contravariant in the `InputType` parameter (or, rather, it would be if you added the `in` keyword to that parameter).  To see why this doesn't make sense, let's look at your example:

You want an implementation of `IMapper<Input, Output>` to be assignable to `IMapper<BaseInput, BaseOutput>`.  Let's say we create some new child class of `BaseInput`, we'll call it `MoreInput`:

```
class MoreInput : BaseInput
{
    public string LotsOfInput { get; set; }
}
```

Okay, now let's say we have a method whose body looks something like this (and that what you wanted actually worked):

```
IMapper<BaseInput, BaseOutput> mapper = new MyMapper();
mapper.Map( new MoreInput() );
```

Well, at this point nothing's wrong: `IMapper<BaseInput, BaseOutput>` has a `Map` method that accepts `BaseInput` as its parameter and `MoreInput` *is a* `BaseInput`, so our call to `Map` is valid.

Except it's not, because the `Map` method we're **really** calling expects an `Input` as its argument and `MoreInput` is not `Input`.  We've broken the type system.

This is what the compiler is telling you when it doesn't let you make that assignment implicitly: that conversion isn't safe.  The compiler can't guarantee that the types you expect are the types you get.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! I'll think of a different way of doing this.